# Break In Attempt

Tags: security

mysql service has vanished from my vps and service is down since yesterday where can see from /var/log/secure file it says break in attempt from an ip that is not known to me but cannot tell if the break in was accomplished by the file except by the fact my server is down.

Under what circumstances does the mysql service disappear? Could that possibly happen when dedicated server my vps is on has maintenance upgrade as they did yesterday?

Also with the secure file message :

```
Jan 12 04:16:51 foo sshd[26725]: Failed password for root from            61.174.51.207 port 1076 ssh2
Jan 12 04:16:54 foo sshd[26822]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication     failures for root
Jan 12 04:16:54 foo sshd[26825]: Failed password for root from     61.174.51.207 port 1076 ssh2
Jan 12 04:16:54 foo sshd[27324]: PAM 5 more authentication failures;    logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=61.174.51.207  user=root
```

Am I reading this correctly that last attempt was successful?

Checking the IP it is in China.

Comment: The service is no longer anywhere on the box? What's the uptime of the system? What's the OS? If possible do a locate `mysql`. Is that gone? Was there an update to the OS?

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) system Centos 6 and my provider had upgrade yesterday but as i said Chinese IP many many break in attempts says in log

Comment: That means it isn't running, not that it isn't available. Please be less vague when asking questions.

Comment: I wouldn't assume a breakin right off the bat. My servers are pounded by this garbage. Doesn't mean anyone is breaking in, just that they're scanning the server. It's called [Internet Background Radiation (IBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise).

Comment: The [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) or [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocam%27s_razor) dictate that your provider doing the update yesterday is likely the reason your service is down now.

Comment: Regarding your Q if this was successful: " PAM 5 more authentication failures; lo...." no that's another failure.

Comment: @slm thanks and Chris I told you when I did `mysql service start` it returned service unrecognised which is not a vague answer. I still cannot get mysql to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service for stopping/starting MySQL is called `mysqld` on CentOS. Try this instead:

```
$ sudo service mysqld restart
```

or this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```